# WinRt :XAML Tag doesnot exist in the namespace

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, prism

I am creating a project to which I want to validate textbox ,therefore use prism for that and implementing example like this below

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xx130660.aspx

All I have implemented worked fine but when I changes the code in Page's xaml than it doesn't find the classes etc. which I have implemented .

For Example

```
<prism:VisualStateAwarePage
     xmlns:prism="using:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.StoreApps"
     xmlns:vm="using:PrismExample.ViewModels"
     xmlns:Behaviors="using:PrismExample.Behaviors"
     x:Class="PrismExample.Views.UserInfoView"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">

<Page.DataContext>
    **<vm:UserInfoViewModel/>**
</Page.DataContext>

<TextBox x:Name="FirstNameValue" Grid.Row="2"
    Text="{Binding UserInfo.FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <!--<Behaviors:HighlightFormFieldOnErrors PropertyErrors="{Binding UserInfo.Errors[FirstName]}">-->
    **<quickstartBehaviors:HighlightFormFieldOnErrors** PropertyErrors="{Binding UserInfo.Errors[FirstName]}" />
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</prism:VisualStateAwarePage>
```

Now here ,the bold text gives the error that it doesnot exists in the namespace.
Can anybody help me out of this. How I can I get rid of this.

Comment: Is this all one assembly? Or are your view-models in a different assembly? If your view-models are in a different assembly then make sure you are referencing that assembly.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    **<vm:UserInfoViewModel/>**
</Page.DataContext>
```

Should this be:

```
<prism:VisualStateAwarePage.DataContext>
   <vm:UserInfoViewModel/>
</prism:VisualStateAwarePage.DataContext>
```

Comment: No, you can reference the base like that.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you reference `quickstartBehaviors` but you only have an XMLNS of `Behaviors` defined in your page. You should look where `HighlightFormFieldOnErrors` is defined.

> Let's pretend that works. But, Noor, I am not sure how to say this. Validation on a control is different than validation in the view model. What I mean is, I think there might be a better way for your to consider. If you are interested, read this: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2014/07/lets-code-handling-validation-in-your.html

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you for your support..But I was just implementing what that article contains..:) I will surely try to understand the referenced article.

Comment: I realize that. I think it's worth pointing out that validation has been removed from Prism. So if you upgrade... :( Sadness.